# Pyinstaller app with PySide6 requires macOS version

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyinstaller, pyside6

So I have created an app with PySide6 and it works as expected when running through the source code (`python main.py`).
I compile my source to an app using `pyinstaller --onedir --hidden-import PySide6 main.py` and when I start the .app it crashes. When I open the ELF executable inside the folder it complains that Qt requires a newer version of macOS.

1. How can I fix this to run on older versions of macOS?
2. Why does this happen considering the python source code can run Qt?

NOTE: I am using python 3.11.7